# add new row in mysql with comma separated text in multiple textbox

Tags: php, mysql, explode

i have this query which is working perfectly.

```
foreach (explode(', ', '$qs_ansen') as $piece) {
    $piece = mysql_real_escape_string(trim ($piece));
    $answers_query = "INSERT INTO answers (answer, qs_id, test_id, ans) 
    VALUES('$piece', '$last_id', '$test_id', '$qs_ansE')";
    mysql_query($answers_query);
}
```

**How so I separate string of two textboxes in one explode or any other way and insert them into separate columns?**

```
foreach (explode(', ', '$qs_ansen, $qs_ansE') as $piece) {
```

Above query is working fine and entering the data. **but i have two textboxes from where i have get data by separating with comma and insert into two different tables. how i can do that??.** i have found other posts but could not made them work

Comment: Do the explode's before the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Gather the data from the tow input fields, explode into pieces and combine into one array that you then iterate through to generate and execute the sql:

```
$pieces=array_merge( explode(',', $qs_ansen), explode(',', $qs_ansE) );
foreach( $pieces as $piece ){
    /* process piece */
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont want to merge i want to get the result separately.......
$pieces=array_merge( explode(',', $qs_ansen), explode(',', $qs_ansE) );
foreach( $peices as $piece1, $piece2 ){
... i want like this

Answer (score 0):

SPL's [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/multipleiterator) can help you with that.
E.g.

```
<?php
$_POST = array( // Only for demostration purposes.....
    'ansE' => '10,11,12,13,14',
    'answer_en' => 'A1,B2,C3,D4'
);

$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( explode(',', $_POST['ansE']) ) );
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( explode(',', $_POST['answer_en']) ) );

foreach( $it as $e ) {
    echo $e[0], ' : ', $e[1], "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
10 : A1
11 : B2
12 : C3
13 : D4
```

and you'd simply use $e[0] and $e[1] in your query.
(Note that the item `14` in ansE hasn't been processed, see [MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php#multipleiterator.constants.mit-need-any))

Btw: The [mysql_* extension is deprecated](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and this kind of processing lends itself to using [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

edit: [sscce](http://sscce.org/) using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
setup($pdo); // boilerplate, seting up temp.tables and sample data for this example

$it = new MultipleIterator;
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( explode(',', $_POST['ansE']) ) );
$it->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( explode(',', $_POST['answer_en']) ) );
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
    INSERT INTO
        soAnswers
        (ansE,answer_en)
    VALUES
        (?,?)
');
// Warning: the prepared statement uses positional placeholders
// This only works as long as the position and the order of the iterators in the multipleiterator are in sync
// (call the two attachIterator the other way round and the result will be wrong)
// named parameters like VALUES (:anse, :answer_en) are a bit more robust in this sense.
foreach( $it as $e ) {
    $stmt->execute( $e );
}

// and now check the contents of the table
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM soAnswers', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
    echo join(', ', $row), "\r\n";
}


// boilerplate, seting up temp.tables and sample data for this example
function setup($pdo) {
    $_POST = array( // 0nly for demostration purposes.....
        'ansE' => '10,11,12,13,14',
        'answer_en' => 'A1,B2,C3,D4'
    );

    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soAnswers (
            id int auto_increment,
            ansE varchar(32),
            answer_en varchar(32),
            primary key(id)
        )
    ');
}
```

Comment: yes exactly what i want ... but for now can u do the setting for my code with mysql? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but no. The line has to be drawn somewhere and the mysql_* has to go (for several reasons; and finding huge amounts of bad tutorials isn't the last of them ;-)) The transition from php4 to php5 took ages and I believe developers in php forums refusing to support php4 any longer had some impact to finally lay php4 to rest. Anyway: You'd have to use $e[0]/$e[1] just like you've used `$piece`in your code.

Comment: But I can provide you with a working PDO_mysql example ;-)